# Understanding the audio fingerprinting file generated using muscg

Tags: java, audio, audio-fingerprinting

I have been using the musicg API to generate the fingerprint information of an audio file. The information is getting saved in a file but the content seems to be encoded. Is there any particular decoder for this file as I am not sure of exactly the format in which its encoded.

I need to decode the file to compare it with metadata information about the audio file in music web apps.